# VNC Viewer that works properly in full screen mode?

Tags: vnc, workspaces, vncviewer

I run xtightvncviwer on Ubuntu. It works adequately in scrolled mode, but thats very awkward viewing against my remote system which uses the hole space. It has a full screen mode, but its badly broken. In that mode terminal input mostly doesn't work, the F8 key doesn't work, and it still shows blank for some of the frame buffer. I run it in a virtual workspace and there is no switching back to the other workspaces.

Is there some vnc viewer that works well in full screen mode in a virtual workspace?